# XML document getting damaged

Tags: c#, xml

I use an XML file in a program I develop.

When I install the program on another machine I get the following error:

```
"XML document must have a top level element".
```

Checking the XML content by WordPad discovered that the XML content was damaged during installation and each '<'  character was replaced with '>' one,  and so is the opposite.

This is the output:

```
?>xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252<?"
```

How can I check such a thing via code and how can I replace the incorrect character?

Thanks!

Comment: That's hard to believe...can you post a sample of the damaged file? Which program has damaged it?

Comment: Instead of '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>' I get '>?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?<'

Comment: Interesting. Which program has generated that file? You should fix *that*.

Comment: Oh, it is not under my control! What else do you suggest?

Comment: mhh you could replace `<>` with `><` than you only need to replace the first char which should be an `>` with `<` and the last char which should be an `<` with `>` and you are done

Comment: It will be better if you post sample file in your question instead of comment,

Answer (score 1):

Here an Example of how you could fix it based on my Comment

```
using System;

namespace replace
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var damaged = ">?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?<"
                            + ">level1<"
                                + ">level2<"
                                    + ">level3<"
                                        + ">Object Value='TEST'<"
                                     + ">/level3<"
                                + ">/level2<"
                             + ">/level1<"
                         + ">/XML<";
            Console.WriteLine("Default:");
            Console.WriteLine(damaged);

            damaged = damaged.Replace("<>", "><");
            Console.WriteLine("Step1:");
            Console.WriteLine(damaged);

            damaged = damaged.ReplaceAt(0, '<');
            var Fixed = damaged.ReplaceAt(damaged.Length - 1, '>');
            Console.WriteLine("Step2:");
            Console.WriteLine(Fixed);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public static class Extension
    {
        public static string ReplaceAt(this string input, int index, char newChar)
        {
            if (input == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
            }
            char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
            chars[index] = newChar;
            return new string(chars);
        }
    }
}
```